# Pointer to Pointer Memory-address

Tags: c++, pointers, variables, memory-address, pointer-to-pointer

about pointers in C++
why we use ** in pointer to pointer

I just want to know the reason
why we use ** in pointer to pointer

what is the main reason of using double indirections ?what is the logic behind it?
or it is just a syntax?

are there any advantages or disadvantages

Comment: Sometimes you want to use a pointer to something. Sometimes the something is an int. So you have a pointer to an int. Sometimes the something is a pointer. So you have a pointer to a pointer. I don't understand why you are confused.

Comment: If you have multiple levels of pointers how else would you represent that other than with `**`? Or are you asking why use multiple levels of pointers in the first place? In modern c++ there aren't many good reasons to do so (see https://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer)

Comment: suppose you write the home address of your friend on a piece of paper. YOu place this piece of paper in your drawer X. Because you have so many drawers you take a piece of paper and write an X on it and put it in your pocket. Now you can always look in your pocket to find where to find the address of your friend.